# Cannot resolve symbol 'newInstance'

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass data from a parent activity to one of its child fragments through a bundle and launch the fragment using `newInstance`, but the symbol cannot be resolved. Any idea on how to solve this and what's causing it?

The bundle is initially being passed from `MainActivity`, to `CharacterInfo` (the code below), then onto the child fragment, `CharacterBasic`.

Thanks for your time.

`f = new CharacterBasic.newInstance(keyId, vName);`

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Bundle charInfo = new Bundle();
    charInfo.putString(NAME, name);
    charInfo.putLong(KEY_ID, keyId);
    Intent characterInfo = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CharacterInfo.class);
    characterInfo.putExtras(charInfo);
    intent = getIntent();
    String vName = intent.getStringExtra(NAME);

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("name", vName);
    CharacterBasic characterBasic = new CharacterBasic();
    characterBasic.setArguments(args);
    Fragment f;

    // TODO: Insert SQLite code, getName
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            mTitle1 = vName + "'s" + " Character Info";
            f = new CharacterBasic.newInstance(keyId, vName);
            break;
        case 1:
            mTitle1 = vName + "'s" + " Skills & Attrs.";
            f = new Display_SkillsAndAttributes();
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle1 = vName + "'s" + " Knowledge";
            f = new Knowledge();
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle1 = vName + "'s" + " Backpack";
            f = new Inventory();
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle1 = vName + "'s" + " Equipped Items";
            f = new Equipped();
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle1 = vName + "'s" + " Damage Tracker";
            f = new DamageTracker();
            break;
        case 6:
            mTitle1 = vName + "'s" + " Combat Sheet";
            f = new CombatSheet();
            break;
        case 7:
            mTitle1 = vName + "'s" + " Social Sheet";
            f = new SocialSheet();
            break;
        default:
            mTitle1 = vName;
            f = new CharacterInfo_Default();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your CharaterBasic class

Comment: remove redundant "new" before  invoking of CharacterBasic.newInstance

Comment: Posting it now. Gimme a minute, please.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. @DmitryArc, thank you for that simple fix.

Comment: was glad to help. happy coding )

Comment: It's probably just `CharacterBasic.newInstance(keyId, vName);` instead of `new CharacterBasic.newInstance(keyId, vName);`

Comment: @DmitryArc why is the new before invocation redundant?  Possible redundant question..